# How to put value/parameter in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

The situation:

User can add an application (channel) that they want. So when user adds an application, one prompt will ask user confirm to add application (*with name of application and ID) or not?

The problem is i don't know how to call/put that value in javascript. hope anyone can help me as well :)

Here code I'm using:

```
Application ID: <input type="text" class="txt" name="widget_id" value="" size="30" /> 
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="box_id" value='<?=$user_box_id;?>'>
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="user_name" value='<?=decode($user_name);?>'>

<input type="submit" class="btn" name="addapp" value="Add Apps"  onClick="javascript:if(confirm('Are You Sure To Add This Apps? ')) location='<?php echo site_url("$url/box/add_User_App/".$Add_apps['box_id']."/".$Add_apps['user_name']."/".encode($Add_apps["widget_id"]) )?>'"></a></td>
```

Comment: Your post is a bit unclear. What is not working?

Comment: this situation i meant: user can add data, when user click add, the prompt up will show ask user confirm to add that data or not and also show data/ID was key in by user.

Comment: @nurfariezza Now I'm more confused.

Comment: @nurfariezza can you maybe give us all of the code? Also, some of your syntax looks scary at best...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onsubmit` event of form to do this

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url("$url/box/add_User_App/".$Add_apps['box_id']."/".$Add_apps['user_name']."/".encode($Add_apps["widget_id"]) )?>" onsubmit="confirmation(event);">
    <input type="text" name="appname" id="appName"/>
    <input type="text" name="appid" id="appID"/>
    <input type="submit" value="go"/>         
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" >
   function confirmation(e){
      var appName = document.getElementById("appName");
      var appID = document.getElementById("appID");
      if(!confirm('Are You Sure To Add This Apps with App Name : ' + appName.value + " and App ID : " + appID.value + " ?")){
          e.preventDefault();
          return false;        
      }
   }
</script>
```

sample : http://jsfiddle.net/diode/5YZh8/2/

Comment: thnks diode. your script also help me. actually i want that prompt-up call back the ID was key in by user. 
example:    Are sure to Add This Apps? 
            App ID: 1234 Apps Name:Test

is it can right?

Comment: i dont know how to implement your script with my script. its not functioning if i totally using your script.

Comment: You will have to integrate this with your script. As I haven't seen your whole script I won't be able to do that.